# Could MATLAB do imshow in a 3-D coordinate?

Tags: matlab

I have a stack of gray value images like 512*512*10 in MATLAB,and I would like to implement a effect like this picture below. I tried imshow in many ways, but images always show in a 2D coordinate, not like the pictures below(a 3D coordinate)
[image]

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not finished code, but everything which is difficult to find in the documentation:

```
surface('XData',[0 1; 0 1],'YData',[0 0; 1 1],...
'ZData',[1 1; 1 1],'CData',flipdim(im2double(img),1),...
'FaceColor','texturemap','EdgeColor','none');
```

Left to you:

- Rotate axis, now it looks like a 2d plot but it is a already a 3d plot
- Draw multiple surfaces in a loop

[image]

Screenshot taken after rotating manually